# how to install open source galago search tool?

Tags: windows-7, open-source, search-engines

**Anyone know how to install galago search on windows 7 SP1?** 
So far I have tried to install galago search engine from galago.bat in the bin folder. The problem Iam guessing lies in the galago.bat install script which appears to be setup for linux or formatted incorrectly at certain points for the command line because I have every prequiste installed except I have the XAMPP version of apache installed.

For reference I have downloaded the zip file and attempted to follow instructions from here

http://code.google.com/p/galagosearch/wiki/Installation

and here

http://galagosearch.org/

more information: I have the windows version installed which is in a zip file. I have java already installed as the above wiki link says is required. The bat file appears to compile some java files together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I worked out by myself was:it was a bad environment variable for the apache maven program. It needs to be installed first before galago can work and  will not install without it. Heres the information I followed to setup apache maven the correct way:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Note: jdk in the link means java development kit. galago is mainly a program meant for educational use and not for production IT environments. The rest is exactly as the instructions above on the google and apache maven pages. The xml in the instructions are used for customization/configuration of the engine but direct programming is not required to use galago or you could go with engine defaults.